# Selectable text in an NSView subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nstextview

I was surprised to see that there was no documentation or examples of any sort on how this would be done, but I was wondering what was the best way to draw and manage selectable text in an `NSView` subclass. I have taken a look at `NSText`, but I think that's a bit overkill for my needs (or is it?). I don't need the text to be editable or anything like that, just simple selectable text (without having to resort to creating separate `NSTextView` instances every time I want selectable text.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an `NSTextView` subview to embed selectable text, but for anyone who's interested, twitter's [TwUI](https://github.com/twitter/twui) framework has a class called `TUITextRenderer` that lets you embed selectable text in a `TUIView` subclass.

Answer (score 3):

`NSTextField` should do it for you. A "label-style" field can be made selectable but not editable.

```
NSTextField * myTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:rectWhereIWantTheTextField];
[myTextField setEditable:NO];
//[myTextField setSelectable:YES];    // This is YES by default
[myTextField setStringValue:myStringForDisplay];
```

Answer (score 3):

Set 'Editable' and 'Field Editor' unchecked from behavior of TextField from Interface Builder. Like this. [image]